# Why am I not receiving data from a form loaded in a partial page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am loading a partial in the homepage, like this:

```
<div class="container">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("ProdutosConsultores");
</div>
```

And in this partial I am loading multiple services that I want to edit at the same time, so I built a form:

```
@using MysticalServices.Models.UtilClasses;
@model IEnumerable<MysticalServices.Models.UtilClasses.ConsultorProdutoCompleto>

<div id="productContainer">
    List of products:
    <form asp-action="SaveProdConsult">
        @foreach(ConsultorProdutoCompleto prod in Model)
        {
            <div class="product-card">
                <input asp-for="@prod.ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId" class="cPInputHidden" type="hidden" value="@prod.ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId" />
                <div class="product-title"> 
                    @prod.Produtos.Nome
                </div>
                <div class="prod-description"> 
                    @prod.Produtos.Descricao
                </div>
                <div class="toggler-container" id="toggler_container_prod_@prod.ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId">
                    <div class="toggler@(prod.ConsultorProdutos.Available ? " positive" : "")" id="toggler_prod_@prod.ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId" data-is-available="@prod.ConsultorProdutos.Available.ToString().ToLower()" onclick="updateProdToggle(@prod.ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId)">
                        <div class="toggle-circle" id="toggle_circle_prod_@prod.ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId" style="@(prod.ConsultorProdutos.Available ? "transform : translate(50px)" : "")"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="status" id="status_prod_@prod.ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId">
                        @if(prod.ConsultorProdutos.Available)
                        {
                            <input asp-for="@prod.ConsultorProdutos.Available" id="available_@prod.ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId" type="hidden" value="1" />
                            <span>Online</span>
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            <input asp-for="@prod.ConsultorProdutos.Available" id="available_@prod.ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId" type="hidden" value="0" />
                            <span>Offline</span>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

My problem now is getting the data so that I can update the Db. I first started doing this on the ViewComponent.cs file of the partial but I was unable to reach it via ajax call or like this. So I eventually gave up and just used the HomeController, because Home is the page where the partial is being rendered.

Althought I can reach the function now ( I know via breakpoint), the data I was supposed to receive is coming up has empty.
Am I missing something at the function?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveProdConsult(List<RequestConsultProdData> requestConsultProdDatas)
{
    Console.WriteLine("HIT");
    return Redirect("~/Index");
}
```

And this is my class:

```
public class RequestConsultProdData
{
    public string ConsultorProdutoId { get; set; }

    public string Available { get; set; }
}
```

And when inspecting the request, I can see that the data is being sent:

[image: Payload from submit btn]

Comment: Call partials using the partial tag e..g <partial name="ProdutosConsultores" model="Model.ConsultorProdutoCompleto" /> or  @Html.RenderPartial("ProdutosConsultores"). Also pass in the model to the partial view.

Answer (score 0):

The Mismatch of **IEnumerable** in the view and the **List** in the action causes the data passing failure. You can modify the code as this sample.

```
@using MysticalServices.Models.UtilClasses
@model IList<MysticalServices.Models.UtilClasses.ConsultorProdutoCompleto>

<div id="productContainer">
    List of products:
    <form asp-action="SaveProdConsult" asp-controller="ConsultorProdutoCompletoes" method="post">
        @for(int i = 0 ; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="product-card">
                <input asp-for="@Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId" class="cPInputHidden" type="hidden" value="@Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId" />
                <div class="product-title">
                    @Model[i].Produtos.Nome
                </div>
                <div class="prod-description">
                    @Model[i].Produtos.Descricao
                </div>
                <div class="toggler-container" id="toggler_container_prod_@Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId">
                    <div class="toggler@(Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.Available.Length > 0 ? " positive" : "")" id="toggler_prod_@Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId" data-is-available="@Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.Available.ToString().ToLower()" onclick="updateProdToggle(@Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId)">
                        <div class="toggle-circle" id="toggle_circle_prod_@Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId" style="@(Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.Available.Length > 0 ? "transform : translate(50px)" : "")"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="status" id="status_prod_@Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId">
                        @if (Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.Available.Length > 0)
                        {
                            <input asp-for="@Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.Available" id="available_@Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId" type="hidden" value="1" />
                            <span>Online</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <input asp-for="@Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.Available" id="available_@Model[i].ConsultorProdutos.ConsultorProdutoId" type="hidden" value="0" />
                            <span>Offline</span>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Meanwhile , keep the model passed same.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveProdConsult(
    List<ConsultorProdutoCompleto> consultorProdutoCompleto)  //List model same with injected in the view
{
    Console.WriteLine("HIT");
    return Redirect("~/ConsultorProdutoCompletoes/test");
}
```

Then you can get the value

[image]